# Changing to CMYK Color Mode Negatively Changes Texture Color That Was Made With Photoshop Colorize Tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, cmyk, rgb

I'm an eCommerce entrepreneur designing packaging for my product and have encountered a problem while wanting to print some packaging with a printing factory.

They accept only CMYK color mode, so everything must be converted to that.

The main element I'm having trouble with is the texture I'm using, as seen below.

[image]

My color scheme is blue, so naturally, I want this texture to be that too. When I've got an image like this and want to change its color, I've learned the Photoshops colorize tool works very well.

[image]

Within Photoshop I would simply hit "Hue, Saturation, Lightness" as shown above.

[image]

Then I would hit the checkbox colorize, and change the hue, saturation and lightness values until I've found shade and tone that I like.

[image]

All is good. However when I then convert this from RBG to CMYK, then the color changes dramatically. Almost like less saturated, or put through the washing machine lol.

[image]

If I go back to the start and change the original texture to CMYK color mode from the beginning, and then proceed to colorize, I reach the same "washed out" color. With CMYK color mode, I can't seem to reach the light blue color I really want. Above is the best I could achieve with every possible value of hue, saturation, and lightness.

I've spent over 5 hours trying lots of different things, and I'm just a bit fed up at the moment. Surely I should be able to achieve the light blue color, but maybe it's not through photoshops colorize tool.

That's why I've come here to get some help outside of my scope of awareness, and would really appreciate any help! :)

Comment: **Many** colors in RGB can never be reproduced in CMYK. Blues are notoriously problematic. There are many duplicates here; https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/problem-converting-color-from-rgb-to-cmyk-for-print

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are my printed colors duller than expected?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57864/why-are-my-printed-colors-duller-than-expected)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem converting color from RGB to CMYK for print](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/problem-converting-color-from-rgb-to-cmyk-for-print)

Comment: Essentially what you want is not possible. The colours you are trying to reproduce are out-of-gamut for CMYK printing. You will need to choose different blues that are in-gamut.

Answer (score 1):

Try colorize it in CMYK mode,instead - you could add a hue/saturation adjustment layer as well. Personally I'll change this layer's blending mode to "color", 'coz hue/saturation's colorize will paint on highlight/shadow area,too, make it unreal and discomforting. Alternatively, you could use solid color adjustment layer, instead (before trying any color, change this layer's blending mode to "color"), now double click this solid color layer's thumbnail and choose any color you want in color palette previewing result effect on the fly, I like it this way, 'coz that  choosing color is intuitive comparing with creating a color, and that color palette is big enough for me to choose color, I don't have to be so careful and subtle, or, it gives me room to be more subtle.