# How to convert grayscale bitmap to one CMYK color in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cmyk

How do you convert a grayscale bitmap a to one CMYK color in Photoshop for printing, eg. C61, M41, Y58, K16 green?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to open your image in grayscale mode in Photoshop (or convert to grayscale mode if it opens it in RGB/CMYK format).

From there, choose Image->Mode->Duotone.

Make sure the type is set to Monotone. Ink 1 will be set to black. Click on the black box, to access a color picker. Choose the color you want (use the color libraries button to get to the list of Pantone colors.) Click okay, and you are done!

Here's how it would look using the RGB values you specified.

[image: Using the RGB values specified to make a monotone image]

Comment: Hey, I want to convert it to #6c7a6c not a Pantone color.

Comment: In the color picker, there should be a place to put in your hex value. What version of Photoshop are you using?

Comment: #6c7a6c is an **RGB** color which is inappropriate for print. You need to pick a Pantone color.

Comment: According to Photoshop's algorithm, PMS 5625 is a fairly close match to your RGB value.

Comment: Why not just use CMYK?

Comment: The idea behind Pantone is that when you pick a pantone color, all (professional) printing services will give you the same color. They've all had their printers calibrated to the same standard, so printing something from one service and printing something at another service won't have color mismatches. This is especially important for branding, as you can imagine. It also allows designers to pick a color using a Pantone deck and know exactly what they're getting without worrying about monitor variances or the differences in emitted light color and reflective color.

Comment: In addition to Anne's comment... You can't get "green" with 1 color and CMYK. Green, at the very least, would take Cyan and Yellow... 2 colors.

Comment: @Josh, I think you threw people a bit there by asking for a CMYK colour in your question, then after Pantone is mentioned, saying "I want to convert it to #6c7a6c", which is RGB. Think might be worth reading up on Pantone: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9397/what-is-a-spot-pantone-colour

Comment: By the way, this is by far the best answer and technique. It avoids any potentially lossy conversion - all it really does is tag the greyscale image to print as tones of the ink colour, and preview in colour. Might be worth noting that you should export in a format that support it e.g.  PDF, not TIFF

Comment: @AnneSullivan How did you come up with PMS 5625 please see my next question...

Comment: @AnneSullivan Wouldn't Pantone 5615C be more accurate.

Comment: I came up with it by putting in the hex code and then clicking color libraries, and that's what Photoshop picked. :) It looks like 5615 is a bit darker, and 5625 is a bit lighter.

Comment: You don't want Pantone if you're printing CMYK. Granted, you can pick a pantone color, then convert the image to CMYK.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, I'll add here that is not always necessary to alter the greyscale bitmap file. If it is in TIFF format and greyscale, and you are using a layout program (indesign, Quark, foo etc) you can use your layout program to tint the image to an exact swatch.

For indesign, you place the image, set the background color of the box to whatever (paper, black, red, purple etc), and then switch the context to the content of the box (aka the image is highlighted brown) and set the foreground color.

The greyscale image essentially acts as an alpha channel for the foreground color. (does not involve clipping paths etc.)

I like this method because it does not alter it (same as the accepted answer,which I upvoted), and it also ensures that the layout program uses the same CMYK or spot color values as all other items in the document (eliminates any chance of a profile or {magic} color adjustment).

In addition, if you change the swatch, it cascades the change throughout the document without the need to edit individually placed files.

Additionally in addition, you can use the same image without alteration with muliple color values. (Think Andy Warhol)

Comment: I completely forgot you could it that simply. Although you might not want to do this if you need to use the colourised image file in other contexts, e.g. output an RGB PNG for web.

Comment: probably even then it will work (milage may vary): presumably you will be exporting a page (etc) and all the items will be afflicted with color drift to the same degree. In this sense it may be desirable for color *consistency* (consistently inaccurate . . .). Your logo will match the spot color shapes, etc.

Comment: I meant an individual image, not a page - I used to have to regularly produce a monotone banner images which would then be used included both in a printed page layout and in a companion web page.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method, if you're not needing to print, is to use blending modes, this way you can pick your exact color:

[image]

[image]

Simply fill a layer and switch out your blending mode!

Comment: One thing to be careful of if you're using this method is that if you give it to a printing service, it will still be RGB/CMYK format (they will show up in your channels tab).

Additionally, this isn't truly one color, as there are areas that are black, or have black mixed with the color.

Comment: Right, and it's not meant to be a solution for printers, your answer is much more qualified for that. The  aim of my answer was to show how to use an exact hex-value color (or any other valued color) and easily blending it on top of something. I figure it'll help someone out in the future :)

Comment: Definitely! It wasn't stated whether the OP would be using a printing service, so this is definitely useful information. :)

Comment: But this question does now specifically mention printing, and so I have to say it is poor advice in this context.

Comment: I made my answer more clear in the fact that this isn't designed for print. The original question made no mention of print and it is a perfectly valid way to add color to a grayscale image and my answer may help someone out in the future who doesn't care about printing. At the time my answer was perfectly valid and I'm not going to retract my answer just because the question was changed making my answer "poor advice." Down voting after the question's context has changed just doesn't make sense to me. The important answer is accepted and most voted on.

Comment: Since CMYK printing *isn't* one color printing, this method should be fine if it meets the aesthetic criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick I use for a lot of things, including your situation. I'm using Photoshop CS6 but this should apply to CS5 and earlier as well:

*Prepare an inverted black and white image...*

1. Convert to RGB if you're not already in RGB (Image > Mode > RGB)
   I know you want to use a CMYK color, but just bear with me on this. The next couple of steps don't work in CMYK or Grayscale.
2. If the image is not already black and white, apply a Black & White adjustment layer (Layer > New Adjustment Layer > Black & White).
3. Next, apply an invert layer on top of that (Layer > New Adjustment Layer > Invert).
4. You should now have an inverted black and white image. The layers should be ordered, from top to bottom: Invert, Black & White, [your image]. Note: Your image should have started with a WHITE background, and should now have a BLACK background.

*Convert the B&W image to a layer mask...*

5. Merge the above mentioned layers together, including your base image (although I would duplicate them first, then merge the duplicates).
6. With the merged layer selected, select all pixels in the layer (Ctrl+A) and copy to the clipboard (Ctrl+C).
7. Open the Channels tab, and create a New Alpha Channel.
8. Paste the pixels into the new Alpha channel (Ctrl+V). Clear the original selection (Ctrl+D).
9. Load the Alpha Channel as a selection (in the bottom of the tool panel, it's the button with the dashed circle). You should see the "marching ants" in the shape of your image. You're almost there.
10. Create a new solid color fill layer (Layer > New Fill Layer > Solid Color...) and pick any color.

*At this point you should have a semi-transparent layer in one color. Now you can add a white background underneath it, or leave it transparent, or burn it onto another layer for a cool effect.*

*In your case you need to convert the document back to CMYK and pick your final CMYK color...*

11. Image > Mode > CMYK – **Don't Merge** and **Don't Flatten**.
12. Double-click the fill layer's icon to pick the exact CMYK color you want.